# How to reference a position in a Set?

Tags: java, collections, set

How can I reference a position within a Set? Like with an array: `array[5];`

I am developing an android soundboard that has a favorites tab. The favorites tab uses a listview . When a user adds a favorite, the text of the button is added to the set.  Now I have setup a contextmenu for the list view to allow the user to delete an item by long pressing, and pushing delete. The context menu passes the position of the list view that triggered the context menu and I am trying to delete that position.

Comment: You might want to look into Iterators.

Comment: Why do you ever need to do this?

Comment: What do you want to achieve with this (loop elements or check existence)?

Comment: I update the post with an explanation

Comment: Be careful while implementing things based on an indexing assumption - most sets (AFAIK) don't let you index them, just act as unique key based lookups.

A higher level point about this is that if a language decides to change it's internal set implementation, any pre-existing sense of ordering might get whacked.

Answer (score 6):

You cannot. [`Set`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html)s have no notion of order, but concrete implementations may.

However, all sets implement `toArray()`, and

> If this set makes any guarantees as to what order its elements are returned by its iterator, this method must return the elements in the same order.

What's your underlying data structure?

Comment: Sets can be ordered. But they don't index their elements

Comment: But still no notion of position - unless you infer it from the ordering of the elements.

Comment: @quaylar "but concrete implementations may."

Comment: You're right, @Voo! The `Set` javadoc states: "As implied by its name, this interface models the mathematical set abstraction."

Comment: Thanks for the explanation @paislee . I am still learning Java/android. I believe my underlying data structure is a TreeSet? I use this Set for a listview in my android application. I have a contextmenu for the listview with a remove option. The contextmenu only passes the position of the item that was long clicked to create  the context menu. So i am trying to delete that position within the Set.

Comment: @Justin V. Can you get the actual element that was removed, instead of its index? That's the best way to remove from a TreeSet... check out the javadoc

Answer (score 3):

You can't - a `Set` does not have indexes for its elements. You have two options, depending on your requirements:

- use a `SetUniqueList` from commons-collections, if you want the properties of `Set` in a `List`
- use `Iterator` (and a foreach loop) if you want to iterate the `Set`